# Why does a page keep loading in the loop?

Tags: python, selenium

In python(Selenium)

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.baidu.com")
for keywords in open('klist','r'):
    driver.get("https://www.baidu.com")
    driver.find_element_by_class_name('...').click()
    ....
```

Although the whole page appears, it just hangs and keeps loading. So a lot of time is wasted.

Not every time it freezes. But once it freezes, it can hang for several minutes before the next step.

[image: loading]

Comment: @salman no error, just freezes

Comment: not local, somebody else meets a simialr problem before https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/7025

Comment: @salam The connection is good. Even after a whole page appears, it keeps  loading.

Comment: @salman it is irrelevant. I try to use WebDriverWait, but it does not work. After the loop goes 150 times, it freezes.

Comment: I revised the post. Basically, it is what it is like now.

Comment: If I click on the button "Stop" in the
browser, the code in python begins to execute.

Comment: So what is your exact Question?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it hangs because some resource loads slowly. You can emulate such behavior manually by setting low bandwidth speed in network tab in developer tools (chrome).
In order to find what exact resource causing the problem in case if it's not reproducible by hands you can use proxy like Fiddler, Browsermob or whatever your favorite proxy is.